# What is the most performant way to create the following MATCH statement and why?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**The question:** 
What is the most performant way to create the following `MATCH` statement and why?

**The detailed problem:** 
Let's say we have a `Place` node with a variable amount of properties and need to look up nodes from potentially billions of nodes by it's category. I'm trying to wrap my head around the performance of each query and it's proving to be quite difficult.

**The possible queries:**

- Match `Place` node using a `property` lookup: 
  `MATCH (entity:Place { category: "Food" })`
- Match `Place` node with `isCategory` relationship to `Food` node: 
  `MATCH (entity:Place)-[:isCategory]->(category:Food)`
- Match `Place` node with `Food` relationship to `Category` node: 
  `MATCH (entity)-[category:Food]->(:Category)`
- Match `Food` node with `isCategoryFor` relationship to `Place` node: 
  `MATCH (category:Food)-[:isCategoryFor]->(entity:place)`

And obviously all the variations in between. With relationship directions going the other way as well.

**More complexity:** 
Let's throw in a little more complexity and say we now need to find all `Place` nodes using multiple categories. For example: Find all `Place` nodes with category `Food` or `Bar`
Would we just tack on another `MATCH` statement? If not, what is the most performant route to take here?

**Extra:** 
Is there a tool to help me describe the traversal process and tell me the best method to choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your domain correctly, I would recommend making your `Category`s into nodes themselves.

```
MERGE (:Category {name:"Food"})
MERGE (:Category {name:"Bar"})
MERGE (:Category {name:"Park"})
```

And connecting each `Place` node to the `Category`s it belongs to.

```
MERGE (:Place {name:"Central Park"})-[:IS_A]->(:Category {name:"Park"})
MERGE (:Place {name:"Joe's Diner"})-[:IS_A]->(:Category {name:"Food"})
MERGE (:Place {name:"Joe's Diner"})-[:IS_A]->(:Category {name:"Bar"})
```

Then, if you want to find `Place`s that belong to a `Category`, it can be pretty quick. Start by matching the category, then branch out to the places related to the category.

```
MATCH (c:Category {name:"Bar"}), (c)<-[:IS_A]-(p:Place)
RETURN p
```

You'll have a relatively limited number of categories, so matching the category will be quick. Then, because of the way Neo4j actually stores data, it will be fast to find all the places related to that category.

**More Complexity**

Finding places within multiple categories will be easy as well.

```
MATCH (c:Category) WHERE c.name = "Bar" OR c.name = "Food", (c)<-[:IS_A]-(p:Place)
RETURN p
```

Again, you just match the categories first (fast because there aren't many of them), then branch out to the connected places.

**Use an Index**

If you want fast, you need to use indexes where it makes sense. In this example, I would use an index on the category's `name` property.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Category(name)
```

Or better yet, use a uniqueness constraint on the category names, which will index them and prevent duplicates.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Category) ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE
```

Indexes (and uniqueness) make a *big* difference on the speed of your queries.

**Why this is fastest**

Neo4j stores nodes and relationships in a very compact, quick-to-access format. Once you have a node or relationship, getting the adjacent relationships or nodes is very fast. However, it stores each node's (and relationship's) properties separately, meaning that looking through properties is relatively slow.

The goal is to get to a starting node as quickly as possible. Once there, traversing related entities is quick. If you only have 1,000 categories, but you have a billion places, it will be faster to pick out an individual `Category` than an individual `Place`. Once you have that starting node, getting to related nodes will be very efficient.

**The Other Options**

Just to reinforce, this is what makes your other options slower or otherwise worse.

In your first example, you are looking through properties on each node to look for the match. Property lookup is slow and you are doing it a billion times. An index can help with this, but it's still a lot of work. Additionally, you are effectively duplicating the category data over each of you billion places, and not taking advantage of Neo4j's strengths.

In all your other examples, your data models seem odd. "Food", "Bar", "Park", etc. are all instances of *categories*, not separate types. They should each be their own node, but they should all have the `Category` label, because that's what they are. In addition, categories are *things*, and thus they should be nodes. A relationship describes the *connection between things*. It does not make sense to use categories in this way.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! I wasn't expecting such a detailed answer. Thank you for the time you put into this. I'd vote more if I could!

Comment: You can also use an IN statement and then provide the list of category-names as a parameter: `MATCH (c:Category)<-[:IS_A]-(p:Place) WHERE c.name IN ["Bar","Food"]
RETURN p`

Comment: You can also easily see the complexity of your query visually if you (in Neo4j 2.2+) prefix your query with `EXPLAIN` or `PROFILE`

Comment: Thanks Michael! That answers the "Extra" section of my question.

Comment: To add to Michael's comment, this URL comes in handy to describe what `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE` do.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html